# Skip disabled li / a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Simple Question: i have a timebar with an disabled a within an li.
I want to click through the timebar with the prev and next buttons. That works fine. Problem is skipping the diabled "0" button. When timebar is f.e. "6" and Next Button is clicked he should go to the "1"-Button. I tried filter the class with **not()**, but that doesn't work for me:

```
pr.find('a.time:last:not("time.disabled")').addClass('active_fp');
```

Here's my fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/2mgj0cr2/44/

Regards John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support the `disabled` at the beginning and in between also then try

```
function follow() {
    var next = $('#timebar li a.active_fp').removeClass('active_fp').parent().nextAll(':has(a.time:not(.disabled)):first');
    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $('#timebar a.time:not(.disabled):first').addClass('active_fp');
    }
    next.find('a').addClass('active_fp');
    var fp = next.find('a').attr('data-id');
    $('#text').html(fp);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/9u5fyhnm/)

Answer (score 1):

Your other selector should be:

[**Updated Example**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/22zxg6pt/)

```
$('#timebar a.time:not(".disabled")').first().addClass('active_fp');
```

Chain the `.first()` method *after* the selector in order to grab the first `a.time` element without class `disabled`.

You also have to check to see if the previous element has the class `.disabled`:

```
if (pr.length === 0 || pr.find('a').hasClass('disabled')) { ... }
```